# Why 'top: 50%' doesn't work?

Tags: css

I want the loading animation in the center of the page. This is the style of the `<div id="loading">`

```css
#loading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

But it isn't in the center and I don't know why. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/skq7Y/) is the loading's jsfiddle page. Can anybody help me?

Comment: That div needs to be inside another one with a size, so this won will have top:50$... try to add another div with height and width

Comment: Your parameters are with respect to the top/left corner of the element.  As others have stated, you need to take its size into account to get it centered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#loading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;  /* half of your element's height */
    margin-left: -25px; /* half of your element's width */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skq7Y/3/)

You might want to read a little more about [vertical centering techniques](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) (in your case it's Method 2)

Comment: Because your image is 50px wide & tall. so half of that centers it within the 50%

Comment: That CSS you did in the DEMO is awesome +1!  Everyone should go check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

When using `top` and `left`, it offsets the top-left corner.
`bottom` and `left` offset the bottom-left.

Basically, you're not telling the browser that the center of #loading should be centered, but instead that the top-left corner should be centered.

---

EDIT: A more promising method of centering a div horizontally is to use `margin: 0 auto;`. That way you don't have to deal with countering by the div's width.

I'm unaware of any single line of CSS that does this vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not accounting for the height and width of your loading spinner, hence it would be a little bit -less- than 50% top & left.

Everyone beat me to the next part but yes you always `divide / 2` the height  & width of your div/image/etc, and that make that *negative* top & left margin.

In your case the Image is 50px wide & tall, divided by 2, boom, you want to use -25px

```
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left:-25px;
```

Here is a good article on the [**negative margin trick**](http://web.enavu.com/snippets/centering-a-div-vertically-and-horizontally-via-pure-css-or-with-js/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/skq7Y/5/